# CLKQuaternion rotation issues

Tags: ios, swift, quaternions, glkit

I am trying to implement the rotation of some vectors by using CLKQuaternions as generated by CoreMotion according to the device rotation.
Here is how my test updated class looks like:

```
     var quaternion:GLKQuaternion{
         get{
             guard let quat = manager.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion   else {
             return GLKQuaternionMake(0,0,0,0)
         }
         return GLKQuaternionMake(Float(quat.x), Float(quat.y), Float(quat.z), Float(quat.w))
       }
    }

import UIKit
import GLKit
class QuaternionMovedSupportView: UIView {
    var myFrame:CGRect
    var controller:OverlayViewController!
    var vector=GLKVector3Make(200, 200, 200)
    init(frame: CGRect, delegate:OverlayViewController) {
        controller=delegate
        myFrame=frame
        super.init(frame:frame)
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("refreshForQuaternion:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    func refreshForQuaternion(timer:NSTimer){
        let referenceQuaternion=BackgroundLocationUpdate.sharedUpdater().quaternion
        print("quaternion \(referenceQuaternion.x), \(referenceQuaternion.y), \(referenceQuaternion.z), \(referenceQuaternion.w)")
        let  adjustedVector=GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(referenceQuaternion, vector);
        print("move to \(adjustedVector.x), \(adjustedVector.y), \(adjustedVector.z)")
       self.controller.moveSupport(CGPointMake(CGFloat(adjustedVector.y), CGFloat(adjustedVector.z)))
    }
```

The previous implementation was wrong as it kept accelerating the vector and that was the reason of its autonomous movement.
Now it actually moves according to the movement of the device but still in an unexpected way.
In particular when I change the device heading going clockwise, it seems to correctly behave by moving to the left, but if I do a round turn, it reappears on the same side.
Conversely when I rotate the device conter-clockwise the box lingers on the right size without moving outside the screen until at a certain point it accelerates and also disappears on the left.
When instead I change the inclination, it draws a sort of parabole between the top two corner with the pick at the center of the screen.
This [video](http://itunes.taxiprofessional.net/tagsMovement.mov) shows both behaviors.

What might be wrong on how I use my attitude quaternion?

A test project may be downloaded from [here](http://itunes.taxiprofessional.net/QuaternionSample.zip) and installed on your device for testing.